# How do I dump custom data to google home?

Tags: automation, google-home

was wondering if I can dump a set of data I have to google home and have the Google home retrieve those on demand.

Answer (score 0):

The way to extend capabilities of a Google Home is by [developing an Action](https://developers.google.com/actions).